# SmtpClient Email Not Sent, Not Caught and Not Logged?

Tags: asp.net, email, iis, smtp, smtpclient

Our website was meant to send out a particular email, it didnt send the email and it also did not log the error which is unusual as i have a try catch setup which should log the entry in the try or catch section.

1) Why did it not log? 
Should i not use Exception and instead use SmtpException and SmptFailedException. If i have this would it have made a difference? If so can you please provide an example.

2) The port we are currently using is 587. As our website is SSL i read we should be using 443 port instead. Would this have made a difference?

The below code is called asynchronously by using

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendInstructions), guid);
```

Which then calls a function that then calls the SendEmail Function below

```
public static bool SendEmail(String strToAddress, String strFromAddress, String strFromName, String strSubject, String strRecipientName, String strBody, String strEmbeddedImagePath, String strEmbeddedImageName, String strCCReminderEmail)
{
try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress(strFromAddress, strFromName),
            new MailAddress(strToAddress, strRecipientName)))
        {
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Subject = strSubject;
            message.Body = strBody;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCCReminderEmail))
                message.CC.Add(strCCReminderEmail);

            client.Send(message);

            LogEmail(strFromAddress, strToAddress, strSubject, "Sent", strBody);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log email
       LogEmail(strFromAddress, strToAddress, strSubject, "Error", strBody);
        throw;
    }
```

}

Comment: Not related to your question, but SmtpClient and MailMessage both implement IDisposable, and should be disposed (as you've done for MailMessage), especially SmtpClient, as it's possible to exhaust its underlying resources.

Comment: Are you sure your SendMail method is being called? Are you sure LogEmail works (do the Sent mails get logged)?

Comment: If there was an exception thrown, your catch should have caught it. Catching a more specific exception won't solve your problem.

Comment: 1) So i should have client.Dispose(); after send?

Comment: You can wrap it in a using block like you do for MailMessage. If you just call dispose after the send, you could still fail to properly dispose if there were an exception thrown between the time you create the client and when you dispose it.

Comment: 3) Thanks for letting me know that it would catch my exception if i use the regular Exception instead of SmtpException

Comment: 2) SendEmail method called. I dont have a way of being able to tell for certain but the SendInstructions function is not in a try catch but the global.asax has a method to send me an email if there is an error. I didnt receive any emails. Its unusual because if i ran the same code with one email address it will work but another one it would not. I cant see why the system would not call based on the email being different.

Comment: 1) Can you provide an example on how i can dispose smtpclient for the example above? im unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar when using

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( new WaitCallback(  ...
```

and then

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient sC = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SMTPHost, SMTPPort);
```

the thread died without throwing an exception.

In my case, the main application thread is exiting before the background threads in the threadpool have had a chance to finish.

The threadpool creates Background worker threads which die as soon as
the main application thread terminates.

so I made a function to sleep 5 seconds and it worked.